# Update Cell With Location of Last Edited Cell - Excel VB Error 28 "Out of stack space"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to essentially get one specific cell to update with the address of the most recently edited cell. I am running into the out of stack space error and I am not sure why. I'm guessing maybe a call isnt finishing and so it just fills the stack with each call?

I have the following code:

Worksheet Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call Module1.last_changed(Target)

End Sub
```

Module Code

```
Public LASTCHANGED As Range

Public Function last_changed(changedCell As Range)

    If LASTCHANGED Is Nothing Then
        Set LASTCHANGED = changedCell
    Else
        LASTCHANGED = changedCell
    End If

    Call last_changed_address

End Function


Public Function last_changed_address()

    Dim address As Variant
    address = Split(LASTCHANGED.address, "$")
    Sheet1.Range("A23").Value = address(1) + address(2)

End Function
```

I also have a global variable which will hold the location of the last edited cell. If there is a better way of doing this than a global variable I am open to discussion. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of a global variable, look up [passing an argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx), which will save some space and is good practice I believe, over Global Variables.

Comment: @BruceWayne where would the value be stored so I can access it at another time such as if another even occurs at some other point in time?

Comment: @Schwagmister - store it in a reference worksheet or on any worksheet will you will not have any other data.

Comment: If a method doesn't return a value than you should be a `Sub` instead of `Function`.  Target is always a valid range reference and will never be nothing in a worksheet event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the out of stack space error because you are re-triggering the `Worksheet_Change` event when you change the value of Range("A23") cuasing an indefinite loop. You need to toggle `EnableEvents` to break the chain.

This should replace all your code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("A23").Value = Target.address(False, False)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Thomas, your code does exactly what I wanted the outcome to be. I just need to look into Scott's recommendation about storing variables in a reference sheet which I can access later.

I guess a parting question is, is there a way to do this without someone actually seeing the reference sheet show up?

Thanks for everyone's input I appreciate it!

To answer the original question, I used Thomas's code exactly.